# How to receive message from kernel in user-mode in c?

Tags: c, windows, kernel

Basically I want to get filepath of every file created in windows using File system minifilter driver on Post Operation and send the filepath to user-mode, I have achieved this using below code:

```
BOOLEAN
GetFullPath(
    IN PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION nameInfo,
    IN PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA FltCallBackData,
    IN PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    IN OUT PUNICODE_STRING pFullPathName){

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(nameInfo);

    BOOLEAN bResult;
    NTSTATUS status;
    PDEVICE_OBJECT pDiskDeviceObject = NULL;
    UNICODE_STRING VolumeName = { 0 };
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION TempNameInfo = NULL;

    PAGED_CODE();

    __try{
        VolumeName.Buffer = NULL;

        // Get the associated file name
        status = FltGetFileNameInformation(FltCallBackData, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED
            | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &TempNameInfo);



        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
            bResult = FALSE;
            __leave;
        }
        status = FltParseFileNameInformation(TempNameInfo);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
            bResult = FALSE;
            __leave;
        }

        // Try to get the volume device object & convert this to the volume name
        status = FltGetDiskDeviceObject(FltObjects->Volume, &pDiskDeviceObject);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
            bResult = FALSE;
            __leave;
        }

        // Get the volume name
        status = IoVolumeDeviceToDosName(pDiskDeviceObject, &VolumeName);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
            bResult = FALSE;
            __leave;
        }

        // Store the filename in pFullPathName
        RtlInitUnicodeString(pFullPathName, (PWSTR)NULL);
        pFullPathName->MaximumLength = (USHORT)(VolumeName.Length +
            TempNameInfo->Name.Length + sizeof(UNICODE_NULL));

        //pFullPathName->Buffer = (PWSTR)ExAllocatePool2(PagedPool,
        //    pFullPathName->MaximumLength, AV_SCAN_CTX_TAG);

        pFullPathName->Buffer = ExAllocatePool2(POOL_FLAG_PAGED, 100, '3331');

        if (pFullPathName->Buffer == NULL){
            AV_DBG_PRINTEX((0, AVDBG_TRACE_ZERO, "Failed to allocate memory\n"));
            bResult = FALSE;
            __leave;
        }
        status = RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString(pFullPathName, &VolumeName);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
            ExFreePool(pFullPathName->Buffer);
            bResult = FALSE;
            __leave;
        }
        pFullPathName->MaximumLength = 100;
        status = RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString(pFullPathName,
            &TempNameInfo->ParentDir);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
            bResult = FALSE;
            __leave;
        }

        status = RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString(pFullPathName,
            &TempNameInfo->FinalComponent);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)){
            ExFreePool(pFullPathName->Buffer);
            bResult = FALSE;
            __leave;
        }

        //DbgPrint(" Full Path Name = %wZ\n", pFullPathName );
        AV_DBG_PRINTEX((0, AVDBG_TRACE_ZERO, "<Fullpath> Full Path Name = %wZ, %d\n", pFullPathName, pFullPathName->Length));
        LARGE_INTEGER timeout = { 0 };
        timeout.QuadPart = 1;
        //timeout.QuadPart = -(timeout.QuadPart * _1ms);
        status = FltSendMessage(Globals.Filter,
            &Globals.ScanClientPort,
            pFullPathName,
            pFullPathName->Length,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &timeout);
        bResult = TRUE;
    }

    __finally{
        // Free all allocated resources
        if (pDiskDeviceObject)
            ObDereferenceObject(pDiskDeviceObject);
        if (VolumeName.Buffer)
            ExFreePool(VolumeName.Buffer);
        if (TempNameInfo)
            FltReleaseFileNameInformation(TempNameInfo);
    }

    return bResult;
}
```

In my kernel debugger, I see the Full file path just as I want it, and then I basically receive that in user-mode as below:

```
int main() {
    ULONG    bytesReturned = 0;
    AV_CONNECTION_CONTEXT connectionCtx = {0};
    COMMAND_MESSAGE commandMessage = { 0 };

    char* buffer = (char *)malloc(500);
    HRESULT hResult = 0;

    printf("Enter your request: ");
    scanf_s("%s", buffer, max_buffer_length);
    printf("Entered request is: %s:%d\n", buffer, strlen(buffer));
    //strncpy_s(buffer,500, "status=sto", 11);
    char recvbuffer[500] = { 0 };
    if (port == NULL) {

        connectionCtx.Type = AvConnectForScan;
        hResult = FilterConnectCommunicationPort(L"\\NeehackAVScanPort", 0, &connectionCtx, sizeof(AV_CONNECTION_CONTEXT), NULL, &port);
        printf("hresult: 0x%08x\n", hResult);
        if (hResult) {
            printf("Failed to Connect to Kernel\n");
            return -1;
        } 
    }
    printf("Connected to kernel, sending: %s:%d\n", buffer, strlen(buffer));

    /*
    hr = FilterSendMessage( Context->ConnectionPort,
                            &commandMessage,
                            sizeof( COMMAND_MESSAGE ),
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            &bytesReturned);
    */
    commandMessage.Command = AvCmdCreateSectionForDataScan;
    hResult = FilterSendMessage(port, &commandMessage, sizeof(COMMAND_MESSAGE), recvbuffer, 500, &bytesReturned);
    printf("sending data hresult: 0x%08x recv:%s\n", hResult, recvbuffer);

    FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER msg;
    //connectionCtx.Type = AvConnectForScan;
    while (true) {
        hResult = FilterGetMessage(port,
            &msg,
            1024,
            NULL);
        printf("message is: %s:%wZ\n", msg, &msg);
    }

    if (FAILED(hResult)) {
        printf("Failed to send data 0x%08x\n", hResult);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("kernel said: %s\n", recvbuffer);

   
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is on `printf("message is: %s:%wZ\n", msg, &msg);` I get null strings or `message is: :(null)` every time the message is sent by the kernel.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're sending the UNICODE_STRING instead of its Buffer member.

Comment: @Luke if I do `pFullPathName->Buffer`, I still get the same result.

Comment: You're also not using `FilterGetMessage` correctly. It fills a buffer with a `FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER` followed by the message data

Comment: @Luke I did hResult = FilterGetMessage(port,             &msg->MessageHeader,             FIELD_OFFSET(SCANNER_MESSAGE, Ovlp),             &msg->Ovlp);         printf("message is #1:%s\n", msg);         printf("message is #2:%s\n", msg->MessageHeader);, now I am getting message is #2:P☺δçm☻. do you know how do I access msg's data buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have both ends of the port agree on the format of the message. Something along the lines of the following just to give an idea:

```
typedef struct _MY_MESSAGE {
    FILTER_MESSAGE_HEADER Header;
    WCHAR FullPathName[1024];
} MY_MESSAGE;

FltSendMessage(pFullPathName->Buffer, pFullPathName->Length)

MY_MESSAGE Message;
FilterGetMessage(&Message.Header, sizeof(Message));
printf("FullPathName: %ls\n", Message.FullPathName);
```

Comment: Thanks for above, it worked. Do you know how do I reply back to the kernel with a simple string I.e "File received"?